# JDBC 3.0 getParameterType call not supported

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

i am getting below exception when trying to insert my rows

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter metadata not available for the given statement
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlParameterMetadata.checkAvailable(MysqlParameterMetadata.java:70)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlParameterMetadata.getParameterType(MysqlParameterMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setNull(StatementCreatorUtils.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:822)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
```

where as my insert was successful, but after seeing the console i found there was exception thrown during my insert.

though this exception doesnt stop my flow, it cause potential issue when there is an error on actual insert, for e.g i have unique column in the table and when i try with duplicate column value , i am not getting the MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException , which i need to handle this.

EDIT:-

```
public int addUserAcc(UserDO userDO)
        throws UserDataException {
    JdbcTemplate jd = this.getJdbctemplate();
    try {
        Long userId= jd.queryForObject(USER_KEY,
                Long.class);
        jd.update(ADD_USERACC, new Object[] { userId,
                userDO.getFirstName(), userDO.getLastName(),
                userDO.getMobile(), userDO.getEmail(),
                userDO.deleteFlag() });
    } catch (DataAccessException dExp) {
        throw new UserDataException(
                "error creating user ", dExp);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? Can you please share the solution if you did? I am facing the same problem right now.

Comment: @cooler I think exception is fine, record can be inserted and exception only be logged in debug mod, which dosent affect other excepitons. `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` can be captured. You can follow the code in spring, its in StatementCreatorUtils.setNull()

Answer (score 0):

I faced same exception, it's because types is not specified as third argument.